# Xcode wait for OS X app to launch error: Lost connection to My Mac

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode6, command-line-interface, lldb

I'm trying to debug a Terminal app upon launch, so I've created a new scheme and selected: [image]

I build my app, then I go to Terminal and run the app. Immediately, instead of hitting a breakpoint, I get:

[image]

And in my terminal the app is run and exited normally, without debugger attached:

[image]

My breakpoint is valid as I hit it when I launch automatically from Xcode.

Cleaned build folder, restarted Xcode etc, no avail. My code is simple as I've just created a default project:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...

    }
    printf("aha");
    return 0;
}
```

In my project settings, I've set a custom location for my executable for debugging to be deterministic (I don't want Xcode to append random strings into the build data in derived data folder):

[image]

Why am I getting this error? How can I debug my executable upon launching from terminal?

Comment: Have you figured out why?

Comment: @hyouuu unfortunately not. I think I was just trying something and gave up the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the app code just as an example or is that what you are really trying to attach to?  The attach wait works by sampling the process list till it sees a process of that name, then attaches to it.  So depending on how far the process has run before lldb manages to attach to it, it may very well have executed the code you set the breakpoint on before it attached.  Especially if not much goes on before the breakpoint.

The best way to arrange to attach to something that you need to run in terminal is to put a spin in the program, like:

```
int keep_spinning = 1
while (keep_spinning)
{
    sleep(1);
}
```

the when you attach, you can set keep_spinning to 0 and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a (command line) unit test implemented with Google gtest, using Xcode 10. My session used "attach automatically", but I had the same problem, consistently. I had a breakpoint set near the beginning of a test case (the only one), and it never stopped, and I got the same message. Even stranger, I got it when I removed all breakpoints and simply tried to run through the program using the debugger. I was however able to get the breakpoint I wanted by setting another breakpoint early in the test's main() function. That can be tricky with gtest, because it's possible to use a generic main that simply launches all tests. Fortunately for me, we roll our own shared main. I put a breakpoint before the call that runs all the tests linked with our main, and it stopped politely as ordered. Then when hit the "continue" button, it stopped at the original break that I wanted. I have no idea why this would work when other things did not, but if anyone else is having a problem like the above, I recommend putting a breakpoint as early in the program as possible and check to see if it gets you out of this particular bind. If you happen to be in EXACTLY the same situation I encountered (that is, you are using a gtest unit test), note that no matter how early in the test instance itself I tried to break, I got the same failure mode. For me, it had to be in main. Best of luck.